# Foreign accents in \document{res}

Tags: accents, french

I get an error every time I try to type

```
Dipl\^ome
```

Accents such as in

```
\'ecole
```

work fine.

I use

```
 \documentclass[margin]{res} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,amsxtra,amscd,verbatim,eucal}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
```

Answer (score 1):

If asking about an error please always show the error that you get and a test file that makes the error.
this runs without error and produces

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,amsxtra,amscd,verbatim,eucal}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

Dipl\^ome

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - I think it now works. I just deleted a few extra lines that were not needed and somehow it works. I am unable to copy and paste from the console for some reason, sorry!